# I cannot find Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs tar.gz file in hadooplibs folder

Tags: apache, hadoop, oozie

I have a problem during Apache Oozie installation. After running "bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests -Dhadoopversion=2.6.0" I cannot find oozie-4.2.0-hadooplibs.tar.gz in hadooplibs/target folder.

Here is installation status:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main ................................. SUCCESS [6.297s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Utils ......................... SUCCESS [5.081s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp hadoop-1-4.2.0 ......... SUCCESS [0.482s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Auth hadoop-1-4.2.0 ........... SUCCESS [0.873s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs .......................... SUCCESS [0.154s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ............................... SUCCESS [4:34.564s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ...................... SUCCESS [9.440s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog ................... SUCCESS [9.007s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ..................... SUCCESS [2.632s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core ................................. SUCCESS [3:08.813s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming .................. SUCCESS [15.194s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ........................ SUCCESS [12.360s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ....................... SUCCESS [14.796s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive 2 ..................... SUCCESS [10.664s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ...................... SUCCESS [8.102s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples ............................. SUCCESS [17.546s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Spark ...................... SUCCESS [16.747s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................ SUCCESS [19.577s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs ................................. SUCCESS [39.197s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ............................... SUCCESS [39.046s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................ SUCCESS [9.844s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................ SUCCESS [2.156s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ............................... SUCCESS [36.911s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie ZooKeeper Security Tests ............. SUCCESS [8.525s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved by moving from 4.2.0 to 4.1.0 version. I have already reported this issue to Oozie bug tracking system.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2297

Comment: have you figured out how to perform oozie operations ? because i am also trying to work on hadoop 2.7.1 and oozie 4.2.0 and got stuck into same problem that i cant even able to perform `oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:9000`.

Comment: @user2511142 sharelib problems are mostly related to the URI. check your URI.

Comment: i figured that out it was related to URI. anyway thanks.